# Share a folder during installation using Inno Setup

Tags: networking, inno-setup, shared-directory

Is it possible to create a network shared folders from an innosetup installation ?

With permissions and all ?

My application uses 2 Shared Folder in the clients network, everyone must be able to Read/Write to those Folders.

I Like to create this in the setup, to avoid doing it manually.
Is IT Possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa389393%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method of the Win32_Share Class.

try this sample

```
Const
 FILE_SHARE = 0;
 MAXIMUM_CONNECTIONS = 25;

function CreateShared(const Path, Name, Description : string):Integer;
var
    FSWbemLocator: Variant;
    FWMIService   : Variant;
    FWbemObjectSet: Variant;
begin
    FSWbemLocator := CreateOleObject('WBEMScripting.SWBEMLocator');
    FWMIService := FSWbemLocator.ConnectServer('', 'root\CIMV2', '', '');
    FWbemObjectSet := FWMIService.Get('Win32_Share');
    Result:=FWbemObjectSet.Create(Path, Name, FILE_SHARE, MAXIMUM_CONNECTIONS, Description);
end;
```

And use in this way

```
  Err:= CreateShared('C:\Foo', 'MyShare','This is a public shared folder'); //0 indicates Success
```

Comment: Thank you for this code, which is helpful but I also need to create a read/write public share which seems to require a Win32_SecurityDescriptor, which I cannot find any relevant examples. Any ideas or links on how to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: @RRUZ This code creates it with a read permission. How can we set both read and write?

Comment: You must use the `SetShareInfo` method of the same WMI class.

Comment: Do you know a way to share an existing folder (not creating a new one)?